# Interpreter over IR without representing everything as an enum?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a simple interpreter over some IR. I know how to do this using enums for both the IR and the return type, but there are a few reasons I don't want to do that:

- I have several partially-overlapping ASTs, and would like to avoid redundant code for each. (For instance, Data and IR share a number of very similar nodes, and it would be good to be able to type IR such that some nodes were only valid in specific contexts)
- I want to be able to do more powerful type inference and `impl`, which is limited when everything in an `enum` is of the same type
- I'm exploring a number of options and want to make sure I've covered my bases

So, I would very much like to get away with both the IR and the return data being represented by traits, like:

```
trait Data{}
trait IR{
    fn evaluate(self) -> Box<dyn Data>;
}
```

But I hit an immediate wall trying to do evaluation:

```
struct Bool(bool);
impl Data for Bool{}
//other things impl Data, of course

struct IfThenElse<T1, T2, T3>{
    condition: T1,
    then_branch: T2,
    else_branch: T3
}
impl<T1, T2, T3> IR for IfThenElse<T1, T2, T3> where T1: IR, T2: IR, T3: IR{
    fn evaluate(self) -> Box<dyn Data>{
        let condition_evaluated = self.condition.evaluate();
        todo!(); //Uh oh: That's a Box<dyn Data>. It's reasonable to fail if it isn't a Bool, but how do I check that?
    }
}
```

Basically, I need to be able to do specific things with the return type. There are several cases where this will be necessary - the IR includes pattern matching, record field access and function application, all of which might conditionally fail if the evaluated return type from a child node can't be inspected.

I can think of a bunch of ways around this, but each has hit a different implementation wall, or at least been messy.:

- `Any` and downcasting
- Having an `enum` encompassing all of the variants of each trait, with functions from and to the trait-implementing structs
- Add a bunch of functions on the `Data` trait to return specific concrete types
- One big enum, with type parameters which can be `!` for certain types, effectively excluding them from those types
- Giving up and just having lots of enums after all

I can ask separate questions for each one, but I think it's more likely I'm missing a more basic and standard approach to this. I tried to find examples of Rust interpreters to look for a standard, but mostly what I found was either about parsing/lexing, or aimed at much more sophisticated and performance-optimized solutions than I need (especially for a first pass).

Is there an elegant way around this with the trait model? If not, how should I be representing data and IR?

Answer (score 1):

From your comments it seems like you want to support dynamically deciding the type of an expression based on the evaluated value. This system is fundamentally in contradiction with compile-time type information, such as traits. As such, you cannot solve this problem with some elegant use of traits.

The primary options are, indeed, either downcasting, enums, or functions to check the type of the data. I don't exactly understand the reasons you don't want an enum so maybe I'm wrong, but I believe an enum is the best fit, at least for the data.

Comment: So using a simple enum representation I run into a few problems - one is the number of redundant nodes and code. For instance, I might have a "Debug" version of the IR that includes some 1-2 constructs that don't exist in the other trees. I'd like to avoid redoing all of the supporting code for every other node to include that - much nicer to say that `DebugIR` doesn't implement the `ProductionIR` trait. I'd like that distinction - `DebugIR` vs `ProductionIR` vs `Data` - to be done statically, and then checking specific variants to still work dynamically.

Comment: Another issue with the pure enum version is that sometimes I need to refer to the type of a particular node. For instance, I may have helper functions that can only handle something like `IR::Lambda` - I can't have an argument typed as one branch of an enum. I could have the enum wrap a struct type, I suppose - that's another model I'm still considering and playing with.

Comment: @EdwardPeters You can make only `Data` enum, not IR.

Comment: One thing I've tried to make work is to have both representations side by side - a `toEnum` function on the trait and a `toTrait` function on the enum. That's hit a wall because of the `impl <T: IR + ?Sized> IR for Box<T>` case, where I can't (that I can see) pass an owned function thru because `T` isn't `Sized`

Comment: So making `Data` an enum may be what it comes to, but I suspect I'll both need to deal with IR variants dynamically (for instance, for matching on/restructuring particular subtrees)) or deal with different "Flavors" of Data. (For instance, there's already a distinction between "Fully evaluated Data that can be divorced from the interpreter" "Results that include first-class functions which may require further interpretation")

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of the `Data` trait? Do you expect it to have any methods, or is it purely a marker trait?

If `IR` is in fact "something that can be evaluated to data", this sounds very much like "data" is meant to be an associated type of the trait:

```rust
trait IR {
    type Output;
    fn evaluate(self) -> Self::Output;
}
```

You can then limit the `IfThenElse` implementation to require that the condition actually evaluates to a Boolean (and where the two branches have the same output type):

```rust
impl<T1, T2, T3> IR for IfThenElse<T1, T2, T3>
where
    T1: IR<Output = bool>,
    T2: IR,
    T3: IR<Output = T2::Output>,
{
    type Output = T2::Output;
    fn evaluate(self) -> Self::Output {
        if self.condition.evaluate() {
            self.then_branch.evaluate()
        } else {
            self.else_branch.evaluate()
        }
    }
}
```

It also avoids the `Box`ed trait object, which seems unnecessary.

If you find that you still need a `Data` trait that must be implemented by the output of *any* IR evaluation, then you can add it as a trait bound on the associated type.

```rust
trait IR {
    type Output: Data;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The problem is that it's really quite difficult to statically know the type an IR will evaluate to. For instance, two of the other IR variants are `Record` and `Field`, where `Record` binds names to different IR, and `Field` takes a record and a name and looks up the record at that name. `Field` would then need its nested `Record` to be an output with the field's output at a particular name - I see no reasonable way to express that, and it only gets worse from there.

More generally, there's no guarantee the type semantics of the implemented language will match those of Rust itself.

Comment: Elaborating on that point - in a dynamically typed language, `if (if cond then "notABool" else true) then "Red" else "Blue")` is a perfectly valid syntactic construction, albeit one that might fail at runtime if `cond` is `true`. I don't think that can be expressed the way you're describing, because the inner `If`'s Output type *wouldn't* be bool.

Comment: Oh, and just to throw more on the fire - the only way to avoid the `Box`'d object is if the type has an almost 1-1 correspondence with the IR being represented. I'm no expert on the rust backend, but I believe that means that Rust would need to generate functions for every specific IR tree it worked across - many of which might not exist until runtime, if the IR is serialized and read from disk.

Comment: Ah, then I misunderstood the "I want to be able to do more powerful type inference" part. Similarly to other dynamically typed languages (e.g. Lua), maybe it's best to choose a set of types that are relevant in your IR. Booleans (or maybe-truthy) values seem interesting for conditions, for example. Can you expand on why the approaches with `Any` and a basic `enum Data` did not work out?

Comment: I didn't go very deep with `Any` because it seems messy, and like a broader tool than I need - given that I have what I (coming from Scala) really want to think of as a "closed" trait, it seems like there should be a more elegant solution. Booleans for conditionals are interesting, and I considered a specific `as_bool(&self) -> Option<bool>` function or some equivalent, but there are too many types that would need such - `Apply` nodes would be a particular nightmare, as the function would have to be coerced not even to a specific type, but to any function type whose input matched the argument.

Comment: `enum Data` would work, and I may be stuck with it. The problem is that there are a lot of repeated nodes - IR and Data both contain the same primitives, lists, tuples and records, for a start. Worse, I expect there to be different specific forms of each for different versions or contexts - for instance, `Debug`-specific nodes of either IR or Data that should not be part of the production use case. Using the `where T1: IR .. ` syntax above, each structure may be described once, have common functionality defined once, and use the powerful impl semantics to be specified to each trait.

Comment: Re: `Apply` nodes. Are there type annotations in the language at all? In a dynamically typed language, I would expect a function type to either carry no information about its types, or maybe its arity. The actual "check" comes from evaluating the function against the data given to it by the function application.

Comment: For the overlapping implementations problem, I am not sure there is much you can do beyond self-imposed code discipline or macro-based solutions (for example, to derive variations on the same enum, but selecting a subset of the variants each time). Unfortunately, limiting enum variants to specific generic bounds is not possible. Note also that `rustc`'s own MIR does not attempt to solve this problem: types like [`StatementKind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nightly-rustc/rustc_middle/mir/enum.StatementKind.html) are used throughout, but variants are documented as "Disallowed after X".

Comment: So dynamically typed was just a simple example of how the type semantics could differ - my actual use case has a statically typed language, though "static" for the IR and "static" for Rust are not the same thing. I do think there's a general problem with equating types of the implemented language to types from the implementing language. My desired behavior is for the Rust backend to handle type errors as runtime errors - for now, `panic!`ing is fine.

Comment: Finally, just to make sure, I wonder if you are not trying to come up with an overly generic abstraction too early. Do you have a prototype/version which works, but maybe is inelegant? Do you already have a "vertical slice" where you can clearly see all the features you would need from the ideal solution?

Comment: Good question on "Overly generic abstraction too early". What I have is complete but problematic implementations in other languages (Scala and Elm). The "Redundant implementation" thing I described is definitely a problem in those implementations. I honestly don't know if that makes this qualify as too early or not, but I'm at least not creating requirements from pure speculation.